# Can't fetch url in scrapy shell with splash

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash, scrapinghub

Please help me!

When I try to fetch a URL in scrapy shell with scrapy splash, I use the following statement to get a response:
`>>> fetch('http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://www.barbiermotorsport.nl/motoren')`

So far I'm not getting a response back, it even freezes scrapy splash (http://localhost:8050/, not reachable anymore in chrome).

When I try a different URL, it works:
`>>> fetch('http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://amtmotors.nl/motoren')
2023-03-14 06:15:21 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened

> > > response
> > > <200 http://localhost:8050/render.html?url=https://amtmotors.nl/motoren>`

in settings.py:
`ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False`

And I also tried several different headers / user-agents. I guess it's stuck on getting a response because of Google Recaptcha, are there any solutions to this?

I was expecting a response or at least a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, it's caused by recaptcha__en.js, filtered it out with the following lua_script:

```
function main(splash, args)
    splash:on_request(function(request)
        if request.url:find('recaptcha__en') ~= nil then
            request:abort()
        end
    end)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    assert(splash:wait(0.5))
    return {
        html = splash:html(),
        png = splash:png(),
        har = splash:har(),
    }
end
```

So if I render it through http://localhost:8050/, it works.

[See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rblZc.png)